# How to split array into elements based

Tags: php, arrays, split

I am using `scandir()` to build an array of image file names in a directory which  contains files such as: `R12345.jpg, R12345_2.jpg, R12346.jpg, R12346_2.jpg, R12346_3.jpg` and so on.

I want to know the best way to split this array into the following elements:

```
R12345,,jpg
R12345,2,jpg
R12346,,jpg
R12346,2,jpg
R12346,3,jpg
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a pattern to the values in the array? If there isn't, then, you might not be able to split it.

Comment: Use a regular expression to match the parts of the filename.

Answer (score 5):

<strike>You can try with:</strike>

```
$input  = 'R12345_2.jpg';  
$output = explode(',', str_replace(array('.', '_'), ',', $input);
```

It will returns you an array:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'R12345' (length=6)
  1 => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => string 'jpg' (length=3)
```

Or using regex:

```
preg_match('/^([^_]*)_?(\d+)?\.(.*)$/', $input, $output);
```

Output:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'R12345.jpg' (length=10)
  1 => string 'R12345' (length=6)
  2 => string '' (length=0)
  3 => string 'jpg' (length=3)
```

With

```
array_shift($output);
```

you can quickly remove first element.

Comment: This won't do the right thing for `R12345.jpg`.

Comment: @Barmar You're right, removed.

Comment: Unfortunately the R12345 part of the file name is not a consistent length....

Answer (score 0):

```
$files_arr  //this contains your files
$final_arr=array();  //this contains final array

foreach($files_arr as $k=>$v)
{
    $test_arr = explode('.',$v);
    $t = explode('_',$test_arr[0]);
    if(empty($t[1]))    $t[1] = '';
    $t[2] = $test_arr[1];

    array_push($final_arr[$k],$t);
}
print_r($final_arr);
```

Comment: This is the same as haz's first answer, see my comment there.

Comment: Oh sorry, Please check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Use [explode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to split the initial array, and then use [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to split the single parts:

```
$str = 'R12345.jpg, R12345_2.jpg, R12346.jpg, R12346_2.jpg, R12346_3.jpg';
$files = explode(',', $str);

$result = array();
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $matches = array();

    preg_match('/^([A-Za-z0-9]+)_?([0-9]*)\.(jpg|png|gif)/$', trim($file), $matches);

    array_shift($matches); // Remove first match that is the whole file name

    array_push($result, $matches);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//Result of $files = implode(', ',$scandirResult);
$files = 'R12345.jpg, R12345_2.jpg, R12346.jpg, R12346_2.jpg, R12346_3.jpg';
preg_match_all('#((R\d+)_?(\d*))\.(\w+)#',$files,$output);
$result = array();
foreach($output[2] as $key => $name)
{
    $result[] = array($name,$output[3][$key],$output[4][$key]);
}
echo '<pre>'.print_r($result,true).'</pre>';
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => R12345
            [1] => 
            [2] => jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => R12345
            [1] => 2
            [2] => jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => R12346
            [1] => 
            [2] => jpg
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => R12346
            [1] => 2
            [2] => jpg
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => R12346
            [1] => 3
            [2] => jpg
        )

)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was after. Thank you @PeterSmith